# Not displaying Input in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, passwords, python-3.6

I want to ask what changes we can make to our input function so that whatever we type as input is represented as a '*'.As we all have seen that when we type a password on the login page it gets written as ******* .Can this be done in python?
something like this:

```
Python 3.6.6 (v3.6.6:4cu1f74eh7, Jun 27 2018, 02:47:15) [MSC v.1900 64 bit 
(Intel)] on win64
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> a = input('Write your password here:')
Write your password here: ************* # we write our password
>>> print(a)
stackoverflow
```

[The `getpass` is not working and giving a warning too.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4FtG.png)

Comment: Looking at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/getpass.html) you can read that **If echo free input is unavailable getpass() falls back to printing a warning message to stream and reading from sys.stdin and issuing a GetPassWarning.**

Comment: @toti08 Thanks! now I know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following library to do so

```
import getpass

pswd = getpass.getpass('Write your password here:')
print(pswd)
```

Comment: Why isn't it doing anything

Comment: It is hiding the input and when you press enter then it is printing the input you made

Answer (score -1):

use [getpass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html)

like

`import getpass
s = getpass.getpass("Write your password here:")
Write your password here:  # input will be hidden`

Comment: Please note that @argo already provided a similar answer, avoid adding duplicates.